# Compression of chess position

Tags: compression, chess

I have developed a chess engine which is playing at roughly 3300 Elo.
I need to process and tune a set of positions I have generated with my engine.
For this, it would be ideal to store roughly more than 1B positions in my RAM.
I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to store pure positional chess data.

Information like castling, en passant etc. can be ignored.

## Ideas

---

1. The naive aproach would be using bitboards which would require exactly 12 bitboards (for each piece)
   which would end up with `12*8=96 byte`.
2. Alternatively, I could only use 8 bitboards where I use 6 for the different pieces and 2 more for the different colors `=64 byte`.
3. Theoretically, I could get away with 7 bitboards using the aproach above. I would not need 2 bitboards for the colors. It would be enough to just have those for white and I could easily conclude if a piece is white or black. `= 56 byte`
4. I could come up with further compression using bitboards which would resolve in `48 byte` yet I cannot get below that with bitboards.
5. One could also store the pure positional information for each piece. e.g. use the first 6 bits for the white king, the next 6 bits for the black king, the next 6 bits for the white queen etc.
   Note that one would require 8*(6+3) bits for pawns here cause pawns could promote to other pieces which would need to be encoded within 3 bits. Problematic would be encoding the absence of a piece.
6. There are some compression techniques like Huffman trees, yet I would also require some fast computation with the pieces on the board.

So what would be the fastest/best compression technique to store a chess position?

Greetings
Finn

Comment: Simple idea: 1 full bitboard marking occupied positions. For the rest of data only code the occupied positions. There will be at most 32 occupied positions, so easy way is to use 4 bytes for the 7 sets of info (color, 6 pieces). That's 36 bytes, if I'm counting right.

Comment: If you don't mind variable sizes of of the different encoded position, extend the above to only encoded info for positions you don't know yet about.

Comment: Mhm. I just found a way to always get away with 24 bytes.
I can use 8 bytes for occupency and the then 4 bits for each piece.
That will be 24 bytes at max.

I wonder if its easy to go lower thant hat

Comment: Is there a significant number of positions that are very similar to each other, so you could add some alternative delta coding? (As in, "take position 123456 and remove piece at F4" or something along those lines)

Comment: Most likely not. Also I need to swap entries sometimes

Comment: I don't get the comment on castling and en passant. Those are moves to go from one board position to another. Moves have nothing to do with the representation of a given board position.

Comment: That is untrue because castling rights as well as a doubled pawn push alter the state of the game

Comment: Ah, ok. I was thinking of "board position" as just that, which is a subset of the state of the game at a given point in time. You mean it to be the complete state of the game at a point in time.

Comment: Another aspect of the game state not included in just one board position is who moves next.

Comment: I mean thats just a single bit. In fact that one is relevant yet I am sure I could fit that one bit somewhere myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huffman codes work well here, and they are likely faster than you think.

Each square is represented by a variable number of bits. The first bit is empty (0), or occupied (1). If 0, then the next bit is for the next square. If 1, then the next bit is white (0) or black (1). The next one to four bits is the type of piece: pawn (0), knight (100), bishop (101), rook (110), queen (1110), king (1111).

This codes a board in 16.9 bytes on average. (Run over one million games.) A full board codes to the maximum of 20.5 bytes.

Decoding can be done very fast with a table lookup. The longest code is six bits. Grab the next six bits and look up in a 64-entry table. Each entry in the table is the contents of the square (e.g. black bishop, white king, empty), and the number of bits in the code (1..6). Drop that many bits, get more bits to fill out what's left to six bits, and repeat.

You can use that to convert to a simple 64-byte representation for fast manipulation, and if needed, the result can be quickly converted back to the compressed form.

More can be shaved off if needed. Represent empty or occupied as eight columns (files), each as eight bits. Huffman code those eight-bit symbols. They can be coded in 6.6 bits on average, dropping the 16.9 bytes to 15.5 bytes.

Instead of one code for the files, you can shave off another 2.2 bytes with four codes for the files: one for a/h, one for b/g, one for c/f, and one for d/e. That gets the average down to 13.3 bytes.

Comment: Impressive answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a chess board compression algorithm used in [nnue-pytorch](https://github.com/glinscott/nnue-pytorch/blob/master/lib/nnue_training_data_formats.h#L4607).

In simpler terms, this compression algorithm works by first creating a bitboard that represents which squares on the chess board are occupied by a piece. This is done by setting a bit to 1 for each square with a piece on it, and leaving it as 0 for empty squares. This results in a 64-bit number.

Next, the algorithm creates a sequence of 4-bit values (nibbles) that represent the type of piece on each occupied square. Each nibble can hold one of 16 possible values, representing each type of piece and some special cases like pawns with en passant square behind them and rooks with castling rights.

The nibbles are then constructed by only storing the values for the occupied squares. This means that if there are only 16 pieces on the board, only 16 nibbles need to be stored. The nibble values are stored in bytes, with each byte holding 2 nibbles.

Finally, the bitboard and the nibbles are combined to create a compressed representation of the chess board. The bitboard takes up the first 8 bytes, followed by the compressed nibbles. The total size of the compressed data is 8 + (N+1)/2 bytes, where N is the number of occupied squares on the board.

Let me give you a few examples.

- For a board position with 3 pieces, there are 3 occupied squares.
  Therefore, we need 8 + (3+1)/2 = 10 bytes to store the position.
- For a board position with 8 pieces, there are 8 occupied squares.
  Therefore, we need 8 + (8+1)/2 = 12 bytes to store the position.
- For a board position with 16 pieces, there are 16 occupied squares.
  Therefore, we need 8 + (16+1)/2 = 16 bytes to store the position.
- For a board position with 24 pieces, there are 24 occupied squares.
  Therefore, we need 8 + (24+1)/2 = 20 bytes to store the position.
- For a board position with 32 pieces, there are 32 occupied squares.
  Therefore, we need 8 + (32+1)/2 = 24 bytes to store the position.

You can find the implementation of this algorithm at https://github.com/glinscott/nnue-pytorch/blob/master/lib/nnue_training_data_formats.h#L4607 written by Tomasz Sobczyk, a Polish computer scientist involved in recent Stockfish development and documentation concerning NNUE.